# android app send message from webservice to android app without using google cloud messaging

Tags: android, sendmessage

i need to create a web service or something else that can send message to android app without using GCM and google cloud messaging .. is any one have a method that can send message to specific device, or specific ip address ?

Comment: a webservice can return a response only if a request comes, and thus if you can send a request from your android app to the webservice, it can send you a response back..

Comment: I think that if i make my app checking the web service every some minutes then the app can read if message is exist and then display it, but this process can consume a lot of internet

Comment: @Lal, although your statement is generally true, the question relates to GCM, which generally works in a way contrary to what you explained. GCM "pushes" stuff to the device (the device periodically polls the Google servers to check if new messages are available for it, but that's none of our concert as developers; it happens under the hood).

Comment: @hasMobi-AndroidApps The Op specified in the question taht he does not want to use GCM and google cloud messaging.

Comment: so my question is about  how to create a small simulator for google cloud messaging using .net and android app, it seems like i want to create an android app that check every 1 minutes the web service if there are new message.

Comment: if it is not accurate, does any one know what is the concept used by google cloud to push the message to the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think third party push services may work, such as Parse from Facebook. Since Google service is not available in China, there are lots of similar services for substitution, such as [Baidu Cloud Push](http://developer.baidu.com/cloud/push) and [Getui](http://www.getui.com/)

Comment: Thank you Bin, is there similar services available out of China and other than google service ?

Comment: Parse will push through their own channel if there is no gcm, see https://parse.com/docs/android/guide for details